# jquery is not working for slidetoggle()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem with jquery. I run my page before 2 days Its worked fine but It is not working now. I have done a sample [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/q37hx6o7/).

**My code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".change").click(function () {
        $(".pass").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".pass1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="change">Change Password</a>
<br/>
<div class="pass">
<br />
<input type="password" class="textbox" placeholder="Current Password" name="old" id="old" size="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="password" class="textbox" placeholder="New Password" name="new" id="new" size="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="add" name="go" id="go">Go</button>
<a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
<a class="change">
    <button class="add" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</a>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: works fine in fiddle.there is no `.pass1` div. what is wrong?

Comment: works fine in fiddle

Comment: ya works fine in fiddle.ant one can check this is web page and let me know that link is working now.All my pages which i used this link is having problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, it's working. I just added `</div>` in HTML section and removed the `script` in JavaScript section

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".change").click(function(){
    $(".pass").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".pass1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="change">Change Password</a>
<br />
<div class="pass">
<br />
<input type="password" class="textbox" placeholder="Current Password" name="old" id="old" size="20" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="password"  class="textbox" placeholder="New Password" name="new" id="new" size="20" />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<button class="add" name="go" id="go">Go</button>
<a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
<a class="change">
    <button class="add" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to post your code in your question because if jsFiddle goes down, your question is useless.

Secondly, the reason *some* of the code might not be working is because `<a class="change"><button class="add" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button></a>` is invalid code. You cannot put a button within an anchor. Either remove the button and style the anchor like a button, or remove the anchor and put the class on the button.

As an example, take the below code and enter it in at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to see the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a class="change"><button class="add" name="cancel" id="cancel">Cancel</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```